# Android - ADB/MonkeyRunner Setting API Levels

Tags: android, python, adb, monkeyrunner

I've downloaded an APK onto a Velocity Cruz Tablet running Android 2.2.1 (API Level 8), and I'm trying to install it via whatever I can manage to make work. I already had ADT on my computer (Windows 8.1 if this helps) for API Level 19 for use with my phone. So I used the SDK Manager to get API Level 8. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make adb or monkeyrunner target API Level 8. I've got the paths right but the problem I'm having is making it target the proper API Level. I've gone through the adb commands, pm commands and MonkeyRunner API Documentation, but I don't see anything helpful. I've decided to come here to see if anyone knows what to do. Thanks.

Comment: They should work on both devices, why do you think you have to set API levels?

Comment: @dtmilano When I try to install it says something which equates to "INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK" when using any of the three methods I've tried.

Comment: You didn't mention what you are trying to achieve, install an APK?

Comment: Ah. Yes. Seems when I was editing it for wording, I accidentally removed that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install an APK which is intended for a higher version onto API level 8 and thus the package manager refuses to install it. It has nothing to do with `adb` or `monkeyrunner`.

Comment: Came back to say that I got an alternative APK and it worked fine.